# How to make questions in the Present Perfect Tense (Perfekt)?

Tags: sentence-structure, conjugation, question, perfect-tense

I started to learn German a few months ago, and right now I'm getting into the Present Perfect tense (Perfekt), so a question came out to me:

How can I make questions in the perfect tense? For example, I've the sentence:

> Ich habe einen Apfel gegessen.

How can I transform that sentence into a question?

Maybe

> Habe ich einen Apfel gegessen?

Comment: Absolutely. There are two related questions (on verb positions in general) [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22253/when-to-use-ist-es-and-when-es-ist/22256#22256) (First answer, side note) and [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11143/when-to-use-gibt-es-and-es-gibt-respectively). The participle (usually "ge-") goes last, like in the main sentence.

Comment: Danke schön, Stephie!

Comment: A collection of possible question: "Was habe ich gegessen?" – "Wer hat einen Apfel gegessen?" – "Habe ich einen Apfel gegessen?" – "Wer hat was gegessen?" – "Was habe ich getan?"

Comment: You're right that the german perfekt would be "Habe ich einen Apfel gegessen?". You could also say "Aß ich einen Apfel?" wich would be the german præteritum (imperfekt) and wich is almost synomymous in modern german.

Answer (score 2):

> Hast du einen Apfel gegessen?

You can always build questions starting with *haben* or *sein* based on the verb which you are using.

For *sein*:

> Ist das Flugzeug nach Berlin schon geflogen?